# electrical box mounting hole doesn't align with cover plate

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, cover

I am trying to install a GFCI receptacle in the garage. The mounting screws/holes on the electrical box are closer than the cover plate. How to align the cover with the box properly? The box is 4' square. Thanks
[image: electrical box]

Comment: That's a surface mount cover plate and you're trying to put it where a mud ring goes. Get a surface mount box like it should be.

Comment: @Mazura Thanks for your response. A surface mount box (without the bracket) actually aligns with the cover plate. I have an unfurnished garage and previously planned to side mount the box to a stud. It won't look nice if I use a mud ring then add a cover on top of it. Any suggestion?

Comment: You have a surface box? Screw it to the stud through the holes on the side. The bracket is to make life easy. But if you are going to drywall it eventually, then you should just put that and a mud ring. Do note that you will damage the ears on the gfci to get it to fit a surface plate, which you may wish you didn't do if you ever go to swap it to a mud ring, because the holes for the cover plate screws will be all bent up. I usually grind them off. You're going to at least have to bend them.

Comment: I don't think mud rings and cover plates have different screw alignments.   This should work.  I use sheet metal shears to trim the ears for these cover plates.

Comment: I compared a mud ring with the cover plate. The screw distance is almost the same. The mud ring I have is still too tight to be aligned. (maybe the mud ring has larger tolerance but I don't think it is designed to align...) I have 3 boxes of both types and can confirm that the mounting ear/wing/tag are all in good shape.
The assistant at homedepot said it's common to bend and align the hole. I tried but no luck

Comment: @Mazura The hole on the side of surface mount box (without bracket) is too close to the edge.

Comment: You can try at an angle but it's tough to get it to end up where you want it. Hold it a little proud of where it belongs; it'll get sucked in. - They *are* called 'surface' mount though... ;) - I looked though my pile and I couldn't find any that didn't match, but I've encountered this problem more than once. *Somebody* was making weird shit in like the 70s.... All I had on hand was modern-ish Raco boxes (TIL: owned by Hubble) and unidentifiable plates. You have a Steel City box.

Answer (score 2):

In this box's design, the box screws are on little "wings" that stick up/out a bit.  At least one of the wings has taken a hit from being dropped, stepped on etc., and is bent in.  It needs to be bent back or the box replaced.

The box is a standard 4x4 box with corner screws.  It should cheerfully accept either a *mud ring* or a *domed cover*.  This is a domed cover, and it's fine.

Comment: "A surface mount box (without the bracket) actually aligns with the cover plate." - anything will take a mud ring. Not all things happily take surface mount cover plates.

Comment: I agree that the flanges make this more suitable for behind-drywall mounting, but it's not like there's some brilliant "reject feature" designed into the screw spacing.  There's only the one screw spacing standard.

Comment: I am thinking to replace the box with bracket but all the 3 boxes have the same issue... And the wings are all in good shape.